# JPA: the better way of getting the first object in a list of ordered objects?

Tags: jpa

I need to retrieve the most recently updated object. Currently I am able to retrieve it by first doing something similar to the following:

```
em.createQuery("select m from MyObject m order by m.updateTime").setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(1).getResultList()
```

and then getting the only object if the result list is not empty. I am curious whether there is any better way of doing this type of thing.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting first result to `0` is redundant in this case and if you need just one row then you could use a [getSingleResult()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()) function.

So your code could be modified as follows:

```
MyObject myObject = em.createQuery("select m from MyObject m order by m.updateTime").setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

**EDIT**: as Tiny has mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529445/jpa-the-better-way-of-getting-the-first-object-in-a-list-of-ordered-objects/29533810#comment47225322_29533810) in case when there are no matching rows the code will throw a `NoResultException` which is to be handled (e.g. assign a `null` value in this case).

**EDIT2**:
I've checked the Hibernate implementation of both methods and it turned out that `getSingleResult()` has all the code that `getResultList()` has and on top of that the following block:

```
    if ( result.size() == 0 ) {
        NoResultException nre = new NoResultException( "No entity found for query" );
        getEntityManager().handlePersistenceException( nre );
        throw nre;
    }
    else if ( result.size() > 1 ) {
        final Set<X> uniqueResult = new HashSet<X>(result);
        if ( uniqueResult.size() > 1 ) {
            NonUniqueResultException nure = new NonUniqueResultException( "result returns more than one elements" );
            getEntityManager().handlePersistenceException( nure );
            throw nure;
        }
        else {
            return uniqueResult.iterator().next();
        }
    }
    else {
        return result.get( 0 );
    }
```

thus you end up with a slower implementation when using `getSingleResult()`.

**EDIT3**: `getSingleResult()` would be beneficial in case if having zero or more than one resulting row is an invalid/exceptional data state (i.e. if such a case occurs then you know that your data is corrupted). Since both `NoResultException` and `NonUniqueResultException` are uncatched exceptions you will end up with only one line of code (no `if`, no `catch` needed in this case).

Comment: `getSingleResult()` succeeds only when the result list contains exactly a single row. Otherwise, it throws an exception, if the result list contains more than one row or it fetches no rows at all. So, it needs to be taken into consideration.

Comment: and it is taken into consideration here `setMaxResults(1)`

Comment: Yes but if the result list contained no rows (in case, the table itself is empty, for example), it would throw the `NoResultException`.

Comment: Sergey and Tiny, thanks so much for your input. A quick question. Is getSingleResult() the better way? I know it is better in code understandability, but throwing an exception makes it undesirable (no need to handle exception in my way). Any other benefits other than code understandability? Regards.

Comment: Sergey, thanks a lot for the follow-up! An informative conclusion to my initial question. Cheers.